# SQLite запрос с LIKE не работает

Tags: android, sqlite, like

Неправильно работает запрос с LIKE. Результат выдает только если вводить точный запрос. Например: Запрос: Покраска - результат Покраска, запрос: Краска - нет результата. В чем моя ошибка. Заранее всем большое спасибо.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    userFilter = findViewById(R.id.userFilter);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final DatabaseAccessSmeta databaseAccessSmeta = DatabaseAccessSmeta.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccessSmeta.open();
    String poisk = userFilter.getText().toString();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccessSmeta.Search(poisk);
    databaseAccessSmeta.close();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.region_list, quotes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String query = (s != null) ? s.toString() : "";
            if (query.length() >= 3) {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            } else {
                // Either set an empty list or change visibility
                listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                adapter.getFilter().filter("");
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        // при изменении текста выполняем фильтрацию
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {  }
    });
}
```

Запрос к базе данных:

```
public List<String> Search(String poisk) {
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    String query;
    query = "SELECT * FROM smeta_name WHERE rabota LIKE '%"+poisk+"%'";
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        mylist.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex("rabota")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return mylist;
}
```

Comment: Потому что К != к

Comment: *В чем моя ошибка.* В полном непонимании того, что делает оператор LIKE. Хотя бы почитали, что ли... вот, в качестве прелюдии к изучению: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=608ac2e83d7afcab3ab274619d650f47

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду что большая и маленькая буквы «к» это разные буквы

Comment: Извините, я пытаюсь реализовать "Живой поиск" по базе данных. Разве оператор LIKE мне не подходит?

Comment: Вам говорят же что регистр букв при поиске имеет значение! Нужно приводить данные в БД и при поиске к одному регистру. Например, вместо `poisk` вставить только буквы нижнего регистра: `poisk.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: С регистром вроде проблем нет. Мне нужно, чтоб поиск работал по части слова, например: чтоб найти "Покраска" достаточно было ввести "крас" , а оно работает только с целыми словами.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `LIKE` в SQLite правильно понимает только символы из набора ASCII:

> Important Note: SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.

[Ссылка на документацию](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Соответственно, засовывать в `LIKE` кириллические символы/выражения бесполезно.

Это не баг, а фича :)

Comment: Я конечно не силён в английском, но по-моему в цитате написано другое: *SQLite по умолчанию понимает верхний/нижний регистр только для символов ASCII. Оператор LIKE по умолчанию чувствителен к регистру для символов Юникода, выходящих за пределы диапазона ASCII.*. Но там не написано что она совсем не понимает non-ASCII символы. Я почему-то думал что Андроид по дефолту включает языковые расширения и даже приблизительно не помню как они включаются.

Comment: Все правильно именно так и написано. Возможно в своем ответе я не совсем верно расставил акценты, но суть простая, `LIKE` в SQLite работает не так как в нормальной СУБД и чувствителен к регистру.